# When/how users of this site will learn to do right flagging?

Tags: discussion, flagging, vote-to-close, exact-duplicates

I have seen many stackexchange sites but only in this sites users don't know where to flag and for what purpose. I have seen many posts with wrong flagging. In this stackexchange, users specially interested to flag a post as dublicate (dont know why).

Here is the [latest example](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23473/hanuman-invisible) which I saw. I have seen many earlier also. One user posted a question and it has been marked as duplicate for no reason. He was asking totally different thing than the mentioned question(Q. that linked to show it is duplicate).

The question which is being said that original question, In that question OP asked where Hanuman lives? But in latest question (which now marked as duplicate) OP is not asking anything about living place of Hanuman! Then how it become duplicate? He is asking totally different thing. Not even one word of his question is duplicate of mentioned one. But still users thinks it is duplicate! On what basis?

He is new user of this site and what a warm welcome he got... This is how old users should treat new users by flagging their question as duplicate which is actually not a duplicate question.

Comment: I too have seen that not just once but many a times. But then we can use our reopen votes when we think a Q is incorrectly marked as duplicate. And, if 5 users including u think similarly the Q will be opened again. Rishabh. Did u use ur vote?

Comment: @rickross Yes I used my vote.

Comment: Doesn't look dupe to me, and after my vote it's finally reopend

Answer (score 2):

> > *"When/how users of this site will learn to do right flagging?"*

Did you mean "vote"? Because flags are seen only by Mods.
Anyhow, above is not a right way to ask a Qn, where you are making a foundation that "Users already don't know the right way of voting."!

Instead you should have asked "Whether closing XYZ Qn, as duplicate right?". That will fetch more objective answers. Assuming that you really want to ask that, here is my take.

---

Like your meta post, the linked Qn in main SE is also making a foundation that "Hanuman is indeed invisible." That's not really a right way of Qn, as people's opinion on Hanuman's visibility greatly differ.

Luckily the Qn is closed as duplicate, instead of opinion based. Duplicate actually serve a good interlinking within SE site and I can assure that, **closing as duplicate it's not an insult for any OP**. In main SO, I have closed many of my own Qn as duplicates to other Qn-s.

Since the OP makes an [misplaced] assumption that Hanuman is invisible. The other users have interpreted the Qn as: "Is Hanuman alive, where is he?" In my personal opinion, it's a matured way of helping the OP. So the users in this case are learned. :-)

A Qn is eligible to be duplicate, if another post's answer is answering that Qn. The 2 Qn-s need not be matching. I see that the users have varied opinion on this. Personally I prefer answer based duplicates.

[When are two questions considered duplicates?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/163449)

> Questions may be duplicates if they have the same (potential) answers. This includes not only word-for-word duplicates, but also the same idea expressed in different words.

Comment: Nice answer, Btw until new user gain privileges for casting close votes, falg servers the similar feature - bring them to a review queue. That's why I think OP is talking about flagging.

Comment: _"Did you mean "vote"? Because flags are seen only by Mods."_ I guess Q. marked as duplicate by flagging, not by votting. "_is not a right way to ask a Qn_" I asked with my understanding. If you feel it offended then it's your personal view. Besides if my Q. is offended then duplicate mark on non-duplicate is more offended.

Comment: _"closing as duplicate it's not an insult for any OP"_ This is hard to understand for new users. They won't know that it is not an insult since they have no idea what is this exactly for? He must be thinking this,"I am asking totally different thing then why this site marked this question as duplicate." Do you think your so deep thoughts about "it's not an insult" can be understandable by OP for now since he is new user? Not, Possible. Forget about new users, I have seen many old users also get offended when they have faith that his/her Q. is not a duplicate.

Comment: _"instead of opinion based"_ Exactly this is what Ithought. THis Q. must have marked as opinion based. If it would have marked as opinion based then OP must have not got offended by any way. Because he must have came to know that this type of question are off-topic here. He must have learned something about rules of this site if it marked as "Opinion based". But marking it as "Duplicate" will only cause OP to get more confuse about whats going on in this site. It will surely demoralizing him to ask more Qs.

Comment: _" people's opinion on Hanuman's visibility greatly differ"_ You know there is body section is also written in his question. Why reading only title...?

Comment: @Pandya, yes new users have flag privilege instead of votes until certain reputation. But even then the flags won't be visible. From above comments, it's apparent that OP indeed meant "flag" & not "vote"; it seems a misunderstanding: *"I guess Q. marked as duplicate by flagging, not by votting"*