# why the constant policing for duplicates?

Tags: discussion

A lot of times, clearly non-duplicates are marked as duplicates.  the poster may or may not have the energy to fight for his question.

Instead if two questions are related, merge them - end of story.  This duplicate policing is one of the reasons why this board totally lacks humor, camaraderie etc.

Comment: [How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10841/260388)

Comment: One doesn't have to fight for preventing duplicates. Duplicate simply means, your question is being answered or should be answered in other thread, Which is either broader or older. Duplicates provide good interlinking within an SE site.

Answer (score 2):

When you find that a post has been inappropriately marked/closed as duplicate.. then first thing to do is cast your own reopen vote..

But understandably, your vote isn't enough and, for that question to be reopened, 4 more votes are needed.

In that case, i think you can raise a meta post to draw attention of other users and then we can discuss the validity of the closure and do accordingly.

So, situation is not that bad and can be handled.

[Here is an example](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1104/when-how-users-of-this-site-will-learn-to-do-right-flagging) of the kind of meta posts i am talking about..

There the question, which was marked as duplicate, was again opened by the other users..

But, if Rishabh did not choose to bring the issue to our notice then that reopening might not have happened at all..

So, IMO it is better to raise a meta in such situations..

Answer (score 0):

here is a case like so many others that degrades the poster with a false "duplicate".

'Do any scriptures condemn atheism? [duplicate]

This question already has an answer here:

```
What is the relationship between Hinduism and atheism? 4 answers
Does Bhagavad Gita detest atheists? 2 answers'
```

the three questions are different and the quality of the board is degraded by this kind of snippiness.

Here is a better way:  mark a question as "tentative" while the duplicate police is doing its thing (there has to be a statute of limitations how long they have to put the duplicate stamp on a question).

Comment: You're talking about cases where Qs closed as duplicates even though they are actually not so.. in those cases we can cast reopen votes.

Comment: thats the point right?  some clique votes your question as duplicate and now you have to get 5 votes to reopen - it is a "guilty until proven innocent" situation

Comment: I sometimes feel like-- "OMG how is this even a dupe of that?" But that's the way it is here.. what can we do other than casting those reopen votes?

Comment: this place has the feel of a prison - prison guards (the ruling clique) and prisoners over whom they rule exercising their petty powers.

Comment: No it is not exactly like that.. we have our powers and privileges too.. we need to make use of them..