# How this question about Vishnu avatara in current mahayuga is a dupe?

Tags: support, closed-questions, specific-question

I asked a question:

[What are all the Vishnu avatar from current Mahayuga according to scriptures?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/24392/76)

then it got closed as a dupe of:

[What is chronological timeline (in Manvantara and Mahayuga) of Lord Vishnu incarnations?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/21692/76)

I left a comment replying to mod who suggested they are dupe with no response at all and I posted reopen vote to and failed to get 5 reopen vote.

Both question are related but not duplicate, other question is even too broad and existing answer is not fully sufficient. I think it need to be reopen and if not then why?

Comment: Why bother ? You have an accepted answer anyway!

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto so we should close everything which have accepted answer because why bother?

Comment: Umm.. not for every question. All I am saying  is before getting closed it as dupe, you got an answer. So..

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto A question should remain open if it is not duplicate. It is not relevant if it has an answer or not. Some user might post a better answer in the future. Who knows.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma *Takes my words back*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should questions which will have exactly the same answers be marked as duplicates?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1109/should-questions-which-will-have-exactly-the-same-answers-be-marked-as-duplicate) ... and ... [When/how users of this site will learn to do right flagging?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1104/1049)

Comment: @iammilind closing different question because there answer is same is so stupid

Comment: It's not stupid, but useful. See from the main meta [When are two questions considered duplicates?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/163449): ***"Questions may be duplicates if they have the same (potential) answers. This includes not only word-for-word duplicates, but also the same idea expressed in different words."*** The duplicate implicitly indicates that, if you have a good answer then instead of posting in 'this' Qn, better to put in 'that' Qn, which is either older, broader or more visible. TheDestroyer's below answer has also reckoned that.

Comment: @iammilind this are borderline cases and they are handled site by site, I don't support closing question based on answer, what if someone make a huge answer which cover 10 more questions too which are not much related , you will close them all too just because of that answer?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is subset of marked question. Vishnu Avatars of [Current Mahayauga](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/24392/3500) are already covered in [question of Manvantara](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/21692/3500) which asks chronological order of all Vishnu Avatars (which also includes 28th Mahayuga).

Hence your question is duplicate of other question.

Comment: Then I am confused abotu the duplicate policy here, it's too vague to understand. Even my question is quite specific then the broad other one.

Comment: @AnkitSharma What is vague here? Are questions which are already subset to other questions not duplicates? I don't think that question is broad, like [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19956/3500) You can use close vote if you feel it is broad question.

Comment: That question asked for whole Manvantara and your answer even partially answered it

Comment: @AnkitSharma let's discuss in https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism